# Вставка переменной php в img src атрибут

Tags: php, html

Необходимо сделать отображение картинки. Путь к файлу лежит в базе данных.

Значение пути из базы присваивается переменной.

Картинка не отображается, хотя путь из базы данных получаем.

```
$query = "SELECT image FROM image_table";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db));

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >0) {
  for ($data = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $data[] = $row);
    $result = '';
    foreach ($data as $elem) {
      $image = $elem['image'];
      echo $image;


      echo '<img src = "$image">';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Покажите то, что у вас в итоге получается в `html`?

Comment: echo '<img src = "'.$image.'">';

Answer (score 1):

Правильно будет наоборот:

```
echo "<img src='$image'>"; // echo "<img src=$image>";
```

Строки в двойных кавычках интерпретатор *PHP* дополнительно проверяет на наличие переменных и если такие находятся, то вместо имени переменной в строку вставляется ее значение. А вот строка, заключенная в апострофы, воспринимается интерпретатором как обычный текст и никаких преобразований в этих строках *PHP* не проводит.

[Мануал по строкам и отличия кавычек](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое,Сергей! Работает!